# Unable to access actuator metrics for spring data redis in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-data-redis, jedis

I'm working with spring boot actuator - 2.6.6 and spring-boot-starter-data-redis - 2.6.6 along with  jedis client - 3.6.3 and I want to enable JMX monitoring so that the metrics of cache hit and misses can be populated in datadog client. I'm creating connection beans in the following way:

```
    @Bean
    public JedisClientConfiguration getJedisClientConfiguration() {
        JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder builder = JedisClientConfiguration.builder();
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setJmxEnabled(true);
        poolConfig.setJmxNameBase("com.example:type=Pools,name=");
        poolConfig.setJmxNamePrefix("Redis Connection Pool");
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(redisPoolSize);
        return builder.usePooling().poolConfig(poolConfig).build();
    }

    @Bean("redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        template.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        return template;
    }
    @Bean("redisCacheManager")
    public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration
                        .defaultCacheConfig()
                        .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer())))
                .enableStatistics()
                .build();
    }
```

but when I open localhost:8080/actuator/metrics, I don't see any metrics available for Redis connection. Can anyone please help here?

I tried adding @ManagedAttribute on the bean but it doesn't work.
I tried adding the following in my application.properties

```
management.endpoints.jmx.domain=example-application-domain
spring.jmx.unique-names=true
spring.jmx.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.jmx.enabled=true
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
spring.redis.cache.enable-statistics=true
```

But this too didn't help.